# Connect HermesJMS to Wildfly 8.2

Tags: jboss, jms, wildfly

we recently changed our Application Server from Glassfish to Wildfly. With Glassfish we used QBrowser to monitor our JMS Queues, sadly that tool does not work with Wildfly.

After a quick search I found the Tool HermesJMS. Although there are lots of guides how to set up a connection to a JMS queue with it I couldn´t find anything directly for the JBoss Wildfly application server. After lots of reading through different guides I think I can now connect to the wildfly server but I just can´t connect to my jms queues.

First I tried to connect via JNDI InitialContext. Here´s my settings for it:

initialContextFactory: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
providerURL: http-remoting://localhost:
urlPkgPrefixes: org.jboss.naming.remote.client
securityPrincipal: admin
securityCredentials: admin

It does connect but all I see are my deployed web applications and a "jms" folder. But they all contain the same web-applications again plus the jms folder and appear as a red circle with a white X in it.

So next I tried to set up a session manually via "Create new JMS Session" with following preferences:

Session: HornetQ
Plugin: HornetQ
Properties:

binding: jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
initialContextFactory: initialContextFactory: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
providerURL: http-remoting://localhost:
urlPkgPrefixes: org.jboss.naming.remote.client

User: guest Password: pass

The guest user is an user I created in Wildfly as an application user

When I then double click on one of the queues it says that there is no such queue.

```
javax.jms.JMSException: There is no queue with name java:jboss/jms/queue/ngsEmailProvRequestQueue
at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQSession.createQueue(HornetQSession.java:397)
at hermes.impl.jms.SimpleDestinationManager.createDesintaion(SimpleDestinationManager.java:60)
at hermes.impl.JNDIDestinationManager.createDesintaion(JNDIDestinationManager.java:105)
at hermes.impl.jms.SimpleDestinationManager.getDestination(SimpleDestinationManager.java:137)
at hermes.impl.jms.AbstractSessionManager.getDestination(AbstractSessionManager.java:387)
at hermes.impl.DefaultHermesImpl.getDestination(DefaultHermesImpl.java:323)
at hermes.browser.tasks.BrowseDestinationTask.invoke(BrowseDestinationTask.java:122)
at hermes.browser.tasks.TaskSupport.run(TaskSupport.java:175)
at hermes.browser.tasks.ThreadPool.run(ThreadPool.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anybody know what I´m missing? Is it even possible to get HermesJms to work with Wildfly? Of if not is there an alternative monitoring tool for JMS queues?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To work with Wildfly, follow this doc: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingHermesJMSWithHornetQ

Second part: `Configuring HermesJMS for JBoss7 / EAP6 with HornetQ`

And change those values:

```
binding=jms/RemoteConnectionFactory

initialContextFactory=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory

providerURL=http-remoting://localhost:8080

urlPkgPrefixes=org.jboss.naming.remote.client
```

In the destinations, change also:

```
Name: sample

Domain: QUEUE
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at JMSToolbox on sourceforge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory

Answer (score 0):

i recently revisited this as the team is moving from glassfish (yaye...) to wildfly. I tried with wildfly9 and it works.
I think it is a matter of exporting your queue name. see below

1. java:/jms/queue/test does not work
2. java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test works

Note: wildfly9.2 is the final version that has hornetq. wildfly 10++ supports artemis instead.

Comment: btw, in wildfly v10++, there is a dependency in redhat 7. redhat 6 will not work because its glibc version is older. hope it helps for those migrating to redhat and wildfly